# Using Spark Cassandra java Connector to append a table

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

```
javaFunctions(recomm).writerBuilder("recommender", "recommendations_wkg", 
mapToRow(Recommendations_wkg.class))
        .saveToCassandra();
```

The code insert into the table but won't update it. If the column exist it inserts a new one. I want to update if I have different info.

Comment: The connector can only upsert (insert-update), I can only guess the issue is something else. Probably primary key collisions in the write itself.

Comment: try with `.mode(SaveMode.APPEND)`... basically cassandra takes care of upsert if same PRIMARY KEY is found

Comment: You know I have a dilemma, If I exclude Rating, a double value, from the clustering key then values get updated and If I include it I can order by rating but now as rating is part of the key a row is considered 'new' with a new rating so it get inserted ..

Comment: I want to order on column not part of the KEY I guess